# What is the best filament to use to create a custom GPU backplate\shroud?

Tags: filament-choice

What would be the best filament type to create a custom backplate\shroud for a GPU?

I'm looking at a design that is largely flat, 3-5 mm thick with a cutout logo and a raised "Tron" style circuit board pattern, and which would be painted using paint that's appropriate for the environment.

Issues of GPU temperature have already been taken into consideration, and aren't going to be a problem. My main concern is backplate warping either on the print bed or after installation

Comment: warping after installation not a heat issue?